# Page Header dynamic height - Components won't "retract" when I don't print anything

Tags: jasper-reports

I Use iReport Designer 5.6.0. and I've got a report with a Page Header and a Detail Band.

In the Page Header I've got some Text Fields in the bottom of the Header, but sometime they'll be not be printed, How can I make the Detail Band goes up, filling the blank space left from the Text Fields?

I already tried configurating it "Position Type" and "Strech Type", same for "isRemoveLineWhenBlank" and "Print When Expression", I can make my application not print something when I don't want it to do it, but, the blank space left from the text that wasn't print, won't retract.

[image: Example 1]

---

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove extra space between textfield in JasperReports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071943/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-textfield-in-jasperreports) & [Remove text field if value in datasource is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7524124/876298)

Comment: Actually I already tried to use "isRemoveLineWhenBlank" and "Print When Expression", but they don't "retract" the blank space left for the component that wasn't printed...this is the problem.

Comment: You are doing something wrong, isRemoveLineWhenBlank=true with a Print When Expression = false, works in pageHeader, check that you do not have other stuff in band. If it still does not work post the jrxml, [edit] the question. I can give you a test jrxml where it works so you can compare with your code.